# Number of meal combinations among 3 people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A restaurant menu has 4 meal options and 7 drink options. 3 people eat at the restaurant. Among the 3 (ignoring order), how many combinations of meals are possible among them? If the restaurant only has one of each meal and one of each drink left, how many combinations are possible (ignoring order)?

For the total combinations, I have $28^3$ since order is ignored. For the second part, would it be 28 times 18 times 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we care about which person eats which meal and who drinks which beverage, the oldest person can choose a meal and a drink in $4 \cdot 7$ ways, the next oldest person can choose a meal and a drink from the remaining options in $3 \cdot 6$ ways, and the youngest person can choose a meal and a drink from the remaining options in $2 \cdot 5$ ways.  Hence, if we care who orders which meal and who orders which drink, the three people can place $$4 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 5$$ orders.  This is what you have calculated.

If you meant the order in which the meals and drinks are ordered does not matter, then your answer is correct.  If you meant it does not matter which person orders which meal or which person orders which drink, read the next paragraph.

If we only care about which meals and which drinks are consumed, then the three meals can be selected from the four available meals in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways and the three drinks can be selected from the seven available drinks in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{3}$$ 
ways to select three different meals and three different drinks at the restaurant.